# oAuth2 and dead access_tokens in database

Tags: django, postgresql, oauth-2.0

I am building web application on top of Django which primary role to serve as backend for mobile applications. For authentication I choosed oAuth2 protocol which is implemented by django-oauth-tookit app.

oAuth2 access_tokens are short-lived, so client apps will change them for new ones very often. As number of users will grow, this can end up in a huge database table with access_tokens which are actually dead.

The question is: should I be concerned about quantity of access_tokens? Do I have to clean them up manually (just by deleting the content of whole table) or do something else?

Thank you for help